# Show images in Libgdx/Scene2D SelectBox

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I have a SelectBox that gets a list of objects that basically encapsulate images and a few more details. Instead of displaying text I'd like to display that TextureRegion.

How would I go about this? As far as I see it, the SelectBox by default displays toString().

So my class looks like that (a bit dumbed down):

```
public class Image
{
    private Vector2 position;
    private TextureRegion sprite;

    public Image(Vector2 position) {...}

    public void render(SpriteBatch batch) { batch.draw{this.sprite, this.position.x ...}

    public String toString() { return "Position: " + position; }
}

SelectBox<Image> selectBox = ... // fetch data
```

Do I need to create my own SelectBoxStyle? If so, how can I overwrite it to be drawing the TextureRegion instead of Text?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @BillLin: I'm not working on that project anymore, but maybe have a look at the one answer available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SelectBox` uses a `List` to display its values. `List` converts its children with this method:

```
protected String toString (T obj) {
    return obj.toString();
}
```

This is not your usual actor that contains and manages its children: it basically has a list of data containers, converting them to string (while allowing you to override its conversion method by extending the class). The rendering method does not expect the data containers to be actors: it simply uses a font to render the text that they are converted into. You would basically have to implement a custom selection actor, possibly using a `Table` (or other container) in a `ScrollPane` with a `TextButton`/`ImageTextButton` storing the current value and opening the menu.

You can try using `VisUI` extension, though. Its menu widget has a similar drop-down behavior and allows you to add icons for each menu entry. Also, `VisUI 1.0.0` added powerful `ListView` widget, which allows you to create customized actors to display a collection of values.

Comment: Note that `VisUI 1.0.0` added powerful `ListView` widget, which allows you to create customized actors to display a collection of values. I updated the answer.